# Counting occurrences of distinct multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the occurrences of a distinct set of cities and countries in a user table.

The table is set out similar to:

```
userid  city       country
------  ---------  --------------
1       Cambridge  United Kingdom
2       London     United Kingdom
3       Cambridge  United Kingdom
4       New York   United States
```

What I need is a list of every city, country pair with the number of occurrences:

```
Cambridge, United Kingdom, 2
London, United Kingdom, 1
New York, United States, 1
```

Currently I run an SQL query to get the distinct pairs:

```
$array = SELECT DISTINCT city, country FROM usertable
```

then read it into an array in PHP, and loop through the array, running a query to count each occurrences for each row in the array:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM usertable
WHERE city = $array['city']
AND   country = $array['country']
```

I'm assuming my scant grasp of SQL is missing something - what would be the correct way to do this, preferably without the intervention of PHP?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
select city, country, count(*)
from usertable
group by city, country
```

Answer (score 10):

What you need is a group by:

```
Select city, country, count(*) as counter
from usertable
group by city, country
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cityandcountry, count(*) as occurrences FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT concat(city, country) FROM tablename
) as baseview;
```

if you want city and country preformated, or

```
SELECT cityandcountry, count(*) as occurrences FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT city, country FROM tablename
) as baseview;
```

if not.

Comment: Thanks - trying this in MySQL, and get the following error: 'Every derived table must have its own alias'

Comment: I believe this won't work.  Each `count(*)` will just be the total number of rows in `baseview`, which is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Did you see the `DISTINCT`? It makes sure, that the `baseview` view only has one line for each possible combination.

Comment: Wow, just over eight years after I made my original comment!  Umm, I still think this query won't work.  Did you test it?

Comment: I use queries like this all the time and I am quite sure I tested it 8 years ago. Obviously I don't know any longer. The important part is the distinct.

Comment: No, the `distinct` won't help you.  There are two problems here.  (1) There's no `cityandcountry` in the subquery.  (2) There's no `group by` to go with the `count(*)`.  When you use `count(*)` without a `group by`, it counts all the rows in the whole query.  It's not what OP wants at all.